# A problem on application of derivatives

Tags: functions, derivatives

So I was solving a question -- Let $f $ be a real valued function on $R$ defined by $f (x)=xe^{-x} $. Suppose a line parallel to the x axis has distinct intersection points $P $ and $Q $ with the curve $y=f (x) $  Also $b $ is the value of $x $ for which $y=f (x) $ has a local maximum and $R$ be the intersection point of the line $x=b $ and the line $PQ $

Prove that $PR < RQ $

**My Attempt**
So I tried to draw the graph of $y=xe^{-x} $ and then this statement seems pretty obvious. I was thinking that is there any other way to solve this question. Perhaps a one bit more mathematical. 
Also $b $ comes out to be equal to $1$

[image]

Comment: As you point out, the value at which $xe^{-x}$ achieves its maximum is $x=1$. Thus, if you have values $z,w$ with $z<1<w$ and $ze^{-z}=we^{-w}$, you just need to show that $1-z<w-1$, which is equivalent to $z+w>2$. Hopefully this helps you get a start